# C-callback without class pointer

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

In my app I use the `JavaScriptCore` API to install a JS function in the WebView context with a C callback in my Cocoa class. Now there is no way I can pass that callback a `userData`/`refcon` pointer to know what class the callback belongs to.

Is there a way to resolve this without passing a pointer? Globals don't seem to work since they get overwritten by other class instances.

Comment: Might want to try that WebScripting protocol I mentioned, it's very easy to do this... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a global won't work (because of multiple / concurrent calls, most likely), then you need some kind of context info.

If the API returns any kind of a unique identifier -- session #, an allocated struct, anything -- you could set up an NSMapTable that maps between that identifier and whatever Objective-C goop you might need.

Comment: The JSContextRef would probably be the thing to use, based on a quick skimming of the docs.

Comment: I've just set up an `NSMutableDictionary` and simply use `JSObjectRef` pointers wrapped in `NSValue`s as keys.